# what does get_byte mean in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
create or replace function  data_to_text(data text)
returns text
AS $$
declare
    raw bytea := ('\x' || replace(data,' ',''))::bytea;
    pos integer := 0;
    len integer;
    res text := '';
begin
    while (octet_length(raw) > pos) loop
        len := (get_byte(raw, pos) -3) / 2;
        exit when len <= 0;
        if pos > 0  then
            res := res || ', ';
        end if;

        res := res || (
            select string_agg( chr(get_byte(raw, i)), '')
            from generate_series(pos+1, pos+len) i
            );
        pos := pos + len + 1;
    end loop;
    return res;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

execute it:  `select * from data_to_text(' 0f 30 38 46 43 43 34 00');`
return `08FCC4`.  It's the same result as hex numbers to text.

`select octet_length ('\x' || replace(' 0f 30 38 46 43 43 34 00',' ','')::bytea);` return 16

Even the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html) already list one example I still not don't understand **get_byte**.
`chr` is roughtly integer to character based on utf8.

Comment: `get_byte(b, n)` returns the value of the nth byte in `b`. What is your question?

Comment: why `select get_byte( ('\x' || replace(' 0f 30 38 46 43 43 34 00',' ',''))::bytea,0);` return 15. I genuinely don't know.

Comment: to  understand this function I first need to understand get_byte. function. now I don't understand get_byte.

Comment: Hexadecimal 0F is decimal 15.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you!  I think I understand most part of  this function.

Comment: Right, it seems simple enough. That's why I wonder what your problem is. Perhaps you should rewrite the question to emphasize which part of the documentation of `get_byte` you don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243244/discussion-between-mark-and-laurenz-albe).